# Angularjs ngModel typing state directive

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm using angularjs to validate a simple form. I'm showing my validation message when the user stops typing. This is part of a custom directive where I validate the entered text for uniqueness on my server.

My code works but I was wondering if there was a way to take the logic that looks if the user is still typing and re-use it in all input directives. It's user friendlier to validate when the user is done typing and not directly when the ngNodel is $dirty.

Example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" name="myInput" ng-minlength="8" />
<p ng-show="myFrm.myInput.$error.ngMinlength && !myFrm.myInput.$typing">invalid</p>
```

So how do I create the $typing part or does it exist in some shape or form?

I created a solution to check if the user is still typing in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gT7gs/)
But it's not re-usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating another directive which solely appends an ngModel status, you can create another directive with the same name as `ngModel` and add your custom behavior with it. Note: you don't have to worry about it overwriting the original `ngModel` directive, it simply runs both  the original and your custom one.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/XL90TMTd81J1xFv02FJ5?p=preview)**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 .directive('ngModel', function($timeout) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
        var promise;

        ngModel.IS_TYPING_INACTIVE = true;

        elem.on('keydown', function() {

          ngModel.IS_TYPING_INACTIVE = false;

          $timeout.cancel(promise);
          promise = $timeout(function() {
            ngModel.IS_TYPING_INACTIVE = true;
          }, 500);

          scope.$apply();

        });
      }
    }
  });
```

**HTML** (sample usage)

```
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{
          'has-error': form.email.$invalid && form.$dirty && form.email.IS_TYPING_INACTIVE,
          'has-success': form.email.$valid && form.$dirty && form.email.IS_TYPING_INACTIVE
        }">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" name="email" ng-minlength="8" placeholder="Email" required>

        <div ng-if="form.email.$invalid && form.$dirty && form.email.IS_TYPING_INACTIVE">
          <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.email.$error.required">This field is required</span>
          <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.email.$error.email">This is not a valid email</span>
          <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.email.$error.minlength">This field must at least have 8 characters</span>
        </div>

        <div ng-if="form.email.$valid && form.$dirty && form.email.IS_TYPING_INACTIVE">
          <span class="help-block">Email is valid</span>
        </div>

      </div>
```